# Copyright content API

Tags: php, api, plagiarism-detection

I am looking to see if there is an automatic "copyright content" API that we can use. I know atrributor have a paid service, but I'm wondering if their is something that effectively does a google search for a portion of the content, to check if whole sentences have been copied from elsewhere.

Basically We have several blogers that write for us and we want to check if any of the articles have been partially or completely copied from another source on the web. Manually I would select a few sample sentences and paste them into Google (using quotation marks) to see if I get any exact matches.

Is there a free API / service that you guys are aware of?

Comment: What kind of content? Text? Images? Video? Audio?

Comment: Text is all I interested with at this point

Comment: Try asking at: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

I was actually reading something about this a few days back and someone mentioned a service called [Copyscape](http://www.copyscape.com/) that has an API in its premium service - not free though

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is use a free search API (e.g.: [Yahoo Boss](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/boss_guide/index.html)).

The idea being is that a couple snippets of text are searched for and the results are evaluated either manually or automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I heard about new service - PlagSpotter. You can read about their API [here](http://www.plagspotter.com/api/). However I think it's not free now.

Comment: Even if its late, someday it will help someone :) Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Copyleaks API](https://api.copyleaks.com). Nice well built API that allows you to query URL or upload a file to check for plagiarism online. 
[Copyleaks homepage](https://copyleaks.com)

Have a good day!

Comment: I found it useful because Copyleaks allows to scan also textual files (pdf, doc, ...), in contrast to other services (like Copyscape).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the idea sounds great, but I do not think that there is anything like that out there and won't be in the next few years. The reason is probably howto define which sentences are copyright protected and which ones are not (every single line from a book or magazine could be copyright protected). Even if this decision could be properly made, it that would lead to a enormous database and request would take a long time.